# Call a .Net DLL during wizard dialogs in Advanced Installer

Tags: .net, powershell, dll, advanced-installer

I'm using Advanced Installer and I need to call a .NET DLL to get a list of items which I want to display in a Listbox in a Wizard Dialog, before anything gets installed.

I intend to call the .NET method from powershell and return the data, which I've tested with a hardcoded path to the DLL on the local system.

The problem is, that this file doesn't get copied onto the local file system until the very start of the Installation itself. So I need a way to deploy that file very early on.

How can I do this?

Comment: So as per the logic. Why dont you initiate the installation and then do a status check. After that directly access the dll remotely and can continue your work.

Comment: How do I initiate the installation? You mean step through the core Wizards like FilePath dialog, then kick off the installation and then do a 'status check'? What is a Status Check? Is that a specific wizard or Install Step?

Comment: @peter.swallow - Have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Advanced Installer has an option to add your DLL as temporary file in "Files and Folders" page. Just add the DLL as temporary file and then call it from your custom action. Temporary files are copied on local system before the wizard dialogs appear.

Comment: I thought the Temporary Files are only copied after all the Wizard Dialogs and just before it started doing the installation? After the FinaliseCost event or something. I tried this, but I couldn't see the Temporary File being output while the Wizard Dialogs were visible.

Comment: A temporary file is extracted under the %temp% folder of the current user account which launched the installation. Have you tried to look in the correct temp location to check this?